# The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm, C# SslStream

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, tls1.2

Following is my Setup for mutual SSL authentication for client/server console app on Windows 10:

1. There is a server listener console app that only accepts TLS 1.0 connections.
2. Client console application uses SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient to configure a secure connection and uses TLS 1.2 connection.
3. I am using the following example for mutual SSL authentication:
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication

**Server code:**

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, true, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

**Client code:**

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName, certificates, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
```

**Error:**

Exception: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.

Inner exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

**Question:**

When i change the SslProtocols to be same in client and server, i.e. TLS 1.0, SSL handshake is successful. 
Why does the handshake fail when the SSL protocol is different on client and server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocols have to be the same. You have to "negotiate" a common protocol between the server and client or they aren't able to speak the same language. The `SslProtocols` enum is marked as `[Flags]` so that you can specify multiple protocols, e.g. `SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls12`

Comment: Reading RFC5246 section on backward compatibility of TLS 2.0, it states TLS versions 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2, and SSL 3.0 are very similar, and use
compatible ClientHello messages; thus, supporting all of them is relatively easy. RFC5246: [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-E). Am i missing anything?

Comment: You're not missing anything.  However the SslStream class will limit what protocols it uses based on what you specify.  So if you require Tls1.2 on the client and the server only accepts 1.0 then it will fail.  in your code you are explicitly making the server require 1.0 and the client require 1.2.  See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145061(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.